# How to make RabbitMQ start and stop faster

Tags: debian, systemd, rabbitmq

On Debian 10, `service rabbitmq-server start` takes 10 seconds; `service rabbitmq-server stop` takes 5 seconds.

This is for a Docker development environment where load is extremely low and start/stop speed is more important than RabbitMQ performance or reliability. Stopping and re-starting the container takes 15 seconds because of this.

How can I make it faster? I added `log.default.level = debug` to `rabbitmq.conf` in case it would show me what it's doing during startup, but it didn't give me anything useful.

Comment: I would run `strace -o strace-log-$(date +%F_%H%M%S).txt -s120  -ttTyfp <rabbitmq-pid>` during those 10 seconds to record how rabbitmq is interacting with the kernel. Add a pastebin link to share the trace with us. Make sure you don't have anything confidential in the trace.

Comment: I run `watch -n 1 'ps aux|grep ^rabbitmq'` during these 10 seconds and there are several processes (more than 10) starting and stopping. Each second they're different. So it's hard to know what you mean by `<rabbitmq-pid>`. I was hoping to just tell it "start in the background", but I couldn't find an easy way to do this with systemd.